# I have a problem with the code vb aatk = matk += 300

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with the code

```
Case 101
    aatk = matk += 100
    Exit Select
```

[image]

Comment: Having `=` and `+=` in the same line doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: As jonsharpe said, the syntax here doesn't make clear what your intention is. Could you tell us exactly what is supposed to happen in those Case, so we have a chance to help you? (also, btw, you don't have to `Exit Select` in VB becasue the Break is implied, which means that even without an `Exit Select`, a Case will not lead to another one. After one match the Select is exited anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: you don't use `=` and `+=` together as in your original question. Nor do you need to specify `Exit Select` because that is already the default behaviour of `Select Case`.

It's a little unclear what you are trying to do with `aatk` and `dadd` so assuming they are integers if you want to have:

`aatk` containing the result of `dadd + value` use this:

```
        Case 100
            aatk = matk + 100
        Case 101
            aatk = matk + 300
        Case 102
            aatk = matk + 500
```

`aatk` containing it's original value summed with the result of `dadd + value` use this:

```
        Case 100
            aatk += matk + 100
        Case 101
            aatk += matk + 300
        Case 102
            aatk += matk + 500
```

I hope this is clear enough for you to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can not have multiple equal signs like that.

Since you did not describe what you want I am going to assume that you want to make aatk equal to mtk + value and increase mtk by value also.

In that case you do it like this:

```
Case 101
        matk += 100
        aatk = matk + 100
Case 102
...
```

Comment: Second line should most likely be `aatk = matk`.

Comment: @Craig Maybe, who knows.